# GitHub Actions jobs sequence

Tags: github, build, github-actions, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I'm trying to implement sequence of jobs on GitHub Actions: checkout and upload arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler, next build matrix of different targets, next create release and upload release assets (matrix).

For checkout I use `actions/checkout@v2` with clean false flag, to split jobs `strategy:matrix:` of course. `fiam/arm-none-eabi-gcc@v1` - uploads gcc.

```
jobs:
  preparation:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
         clean: false
    - name: Install python dependencies
      run: |
        python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python3 -m pip install -r ./tools/requirements.txt
    - name: Install arm-none-eabi-gcc
      uses: fiam/arm-none-eabi-gcc@v1
      with:
        release: '9-2019-q4' # The arm-none-eabi-gcc release to use.
  build:
    needs: preparation
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
    *** build cmds ***
  release:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Create Release
      id: create_release
      uses: actions/create-release@v1

  upload:
    needs: release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
```

I have two splits at build and at upload jobs.

Is it possible to create this sequence in github actions?
How can I disable Post checkout cleanup to store uploaded compiler?

Comment: Have you tried it? Are you encountering any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only two ways to share files between jobs:

1. [Cache](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/advanced-guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows)
2. [Artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/advanced-guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts)